# How to plot multiple cones based on an array

Tags: graphics

I need to plot multiple cones, I could of course type Cone[] multiple times but the programmer in me just knows there has to be a way to do it in one line.

My cone currently looks like this:

Graphics3DGraphics3D[Cone[{{0, 0, m}, {0, 0, 0}}, r]]

Very simple, but rather than manipulating m and only creating one cone at a time, I need m to be an array of integer values, it could be anything but let's just say {-2, -1, 0, 1, 2}, to plot 5 (length of the list in this case) cones at once, each one that has 'm' take on one of the values in the list.

Comment: Have you tried `Graphics3DGraphics3D[Cone[{{0, 0, m}, {0, 0, 0}}, r]]` with *any* values of `m` and `r`?  If you use `Graphics3D` instead of `Graphics3DGraphics3D`, does `m = 0`, `r = 1` show a cone? -- The errors make me wonder whether the question is correctly stated. What are you trying to show, a bunch of cone with the origin as a vertex? Do you want a disk in the xy plane centered at the origin, which is how I would interpret `m = 0`?

Comment: that was obviously a typo, and i think you know it

Comment: `Graphics3DGraphics3D` - yes, a typo, one that should be fixed along with the formatting. `m = 0` - no, I thought that was not typo. Together, they undermined my feeling of confidence in the question.

Comment: yes the m=0 does not show a cone, but i do want a disk there, like the answer you gave so thank you. Very new to mathematica (this problem was assigned to me for homework) and stackexchange as well, so I also apologize for the formatting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a guess:

```
Block[{r = 1},
 Graphics3D[{
   GeometricTransformation[
    Cone[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, r], 
    Table[ScalingTransform[{1, 1, m}], {m, -2, 2}]
    ]}]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: This is it! Thank you!

Comment: @meek0 You're welcome. Note that `GeometricTransform` is an efficient way to make multiple (transformed) copies of a geometric object, usually saving much time and memory.

Answer (score 0):

Graphic3D[Table[Cone[{{0,0,m},{0,0,0}},r],{m,-2,2}]]

Comment: @ Legion, You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful